# Excel Data for Looping Using Python Pandas before Django Model Insert

Tags: python, pandas, django-models

I have an excel file with the following format, there is a `UNIT column`, an `ELEMENT column` and a `SEL column`, then I want to insert the data into the database using the following Django model schema. my question is how to do the trick for looping the excel data with a structure like `parent` -> `child 1` -> `child 2`

```
excel data struktur
```

[image]

```
django models
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```py
for line in sheet:
    unit, element, sel = line
    if unit:
        unit_obj = Unit.objects.create(nama_unit=unit)
    if element:
        element_obj = Element.objects.create(nama_element=element, unit=unit_obj)
    if sel:
        SEL.objects.create(nama_sel=sel, elemen=element_obj)
```

I used Python's variable scope.